# Switch Between Classes in Java?

Tags: java

I want to create a class for Heap data structure in Java that allows the user to choose either MinHeap or MaxHeap

the constructor should look like this:

```
public Heap(String type) {
    if (type.equals("min")) {
        //allow this object only to use methods for MinHeap
    } else {
        //allow this object only to use methods for MaxHeap
    }
}
```

Note that the methods really differ from between the 2 types. For example this method is used in MaxHeaps and would not be implemented the same way in MinHeap:

```
 public void maxHeapify(int i, int n) {
       int l = leftPos(i);
       int r = rightPos(i);
       int largest;
       if (l < n && heap.get(l) > heap.get(i)) {
           largest = l;
       } else {
           largest = i;
       }
       if (r < n && heap.get(r) > heap.get(largest)) {
           largest = r;
       }
       if (largest != i) {
           swap(i, largest);
           maxHeapify(largest, n);
        }
    }
```

I use an array to represent the MaxHeap.

Is it possible? Or should I make separate classes for MaxHeap and MinHeap; each with its specific methods? or do you think I should follow this way: Example:

```
 public void getMax() {
      if (type.equals("min")) {
            //use the method for MinHeap
      } else {
           //apply the method for MaxHeap
      }
 }
```

Feel free to change the title of the question cause I didn't know how exactly to ask it

Comment: Better to have two separate classes, and a third `master` one implementing only a `public static` method building either of the other two as appropriate.

Comment: 1+ @AlexMartelli ... and instead of a `String`, an enumeration would be better in your constructor

Comment: Is there any real difference in interface? Both have the same heapify and get-top-element methods, it's just the ordering/definition of top that differ. So one class, with a different comparison function, and a  master 'factory' that creates the heap, passing the appropriate comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a `Heap` interface with two implementing classes - `MinHeap` and `MaxHeap`. This is how the Collections API is designed. For example, The `List` interface has many implementations, some of which include `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it with a single class similar to the way [`java.util.PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is implemented. You can switch the priority by passing the appropriate comparator class.

This is similar to the constructor `PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)` as described in the Javadocs:

> Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator.